# Exponential intertwining of linear and local actions.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

I am reading Duistermaat's 1973 paper on relating the convexity of the image of a moment map to the image of the fixed points of an antisymplectic involution. In that paper, the following comment is made:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold endowed with a smooth action of a compact group $G$. If $\beta$ is a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric (always possible since $G$ is compact) and $m \in M$ is a fixed point of the $G$-action, then the $\beta$-exponential map at $m$ intertwines the linear action of $G$ on $T_mM$ and the local action of $G$ around $m$.

My interpretation of this statement is as follows: If $A_g: M \to M, m\mapsto g\cdot m$ denotes the action of $g \in G$ and $\exp_m: T_m M \to M$ is the $\beta$-exponential map, then
$$ \exp_m \circ d_m A_g = A_g\circ \exp_m.$$

Now I believe this is true if $G=M$, since in that case it is known that the $\beta$-Riemannian and Lie exponential coincide (though I would love a reference for this) and this should boil down to a statement regarding the the functorial nature of the exponential, but it is not clear to me why this is true in the more general case.

Comment: $\forall v \in T_mM$, $\gamma: t \mapsto \exp_m(tv)$ is a geodesic with velocity $v$. Since $A_g$ is an isometry, $A_g(\gamma)$ is also a geodesic with volecity $dA_g(v)$.

Comment: @XipanXiao You are, of course, correct. Upon reflection, this is really just the statement that the exponential map is functorial with respect to isometries, and the action is clearly an isometry by invariance of the metric.